# How to debug Ruby On Rails on AWS OpsWorks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, aws-opsworks

After Serval days testing for how to deploy my ROR project on AWS EC2.
Rubber,eb,at last I decided to use OPSWORKS because of a [video in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHu8fCp9GR4).
But the deployment still hard.

- OK,My question is:How to debug Ruby On Rails on AWS OpsWorks?

I've know

1. In the web console,we can get deploy log.
2. Via ssh,we can get [apptest].access.log,error.log,access.log in the path
   /var/log/nginx/(I test with nginx and Unicorn)

But all of below is log about deployment,and few logs/infos about access website.
For example:(**test.access.log**)

```
133.255.255.124 - - [25/Jun/2014:15:10:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.76.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.4 Safari/537.76.4"
133.255.255.124 - - [25/Jun/2014:15:10:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.76.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.4 Safari/537.76.4"
```

while I got 500 .where can I found detail about this information?
Here is **error.log** in nginx

```
 1. 2014/06/25 13:35:59 [emerg] 5502#0: still could not bind()
 2. 2014/06/25 15:23:06 [crit] 11593#0: *2 connect() to
    unix:/srv/www/test/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (2: No such
    file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client:
    133.255.255.124, server: test, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/srv/www/test/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock:/", host:
    "55.218.118.37"
```

you can find during 500 return ,error.log info is useless,and **access.log** is nothing to show.

- **Where Can I get detail Debug info while visit test website,like tomcat server**
  Thanks a lot.

Here is something in unicorn.stderr.log,and  production.log unicorn.stdout.log
is nothing to show.even I set `config.log_level = :debug` in production.rb and restart the web server.

```
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:18.172877 #6436]  INFO -- : executing ["/home/deploy/.bundler/test/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails", "--env", "production", "--daemonize", "-c", "/srv/www/test/shared/config/unicorn.conf", {10=>#<Kgio::UNIXServer:fd 10>}] (in /srv/www/test/releases/20140625234506)
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:19.196006 #6436]  INFO -- : inherited addr=/srv/www/test/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fd=10
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:19.196505 #6436]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:23.769647 #6449]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:23.811102 #6436]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:23.848092 #6452]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:24.129596 #5830]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5852 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:24.129878 #5830]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5855 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2014-06-25T23:45:24.129967 #5830]  INFO -- : master complete
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to do something like the following after logging in :

```
sudo su deploy
cd /srv/www/#{application_name}/shared/log/
```

The files are stored under :

```
/srv/www/#{application_name}/shared/log
➜  log  ls -lsh *.log
 32K -rw-r--r-- 1 deploy www-data  32K Jun 25 20:45 cron-error.log
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 deploy www-data 1.6K Jun 25 20:30 cron.log
192K -rw-r--r-- 1 deploy www-data 188K Jun 25 20:45 newrelic_agent.log
 48M -rw-r--r-- 1 deploy www-data  47M Jun 25 20:55 staging.log
   0 -rw-r--r-- 1 deploy www-data    0 Jun 24 06:46 unicorn.stderr.log
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 deploy www-data 3.1K Jun 25 08:49 unicorn.stdout.log
```

NOTE : #{application_name} is whatever your shortcode is for the application.

Comment: In my dir(shared/log) have 3  production.log  unicorn.stderr.log  unicorn.stdout.log

Comment: did you deploy after making the changes ?

Comment: Yes,but still not work.I'm newer to ruby,and rails.maybe it's too hard to start!

Comment: Restart the webserver and a reboot if needed

Comment: For some reason in my deployment of a Rails app in Opsworks, despite having correct Unicorn configuration, it logs all Rails activity in unicorn.stderr.log   (including access), which is why production.log and unicorn.stdout.log are empty.   Check unicorn.stderr.log to see if that's the case with you.